# Looping in Informatica Cloud

Tags: loops, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have an excel where data is present in key-value format.
Id     D-id
2      Null
14     2
110    14
203    110

Here 203 is linked to 110, 110 is linked to 14, 14 to 2. My final goal is to map 203 to 2. Final output will look like
Parent   Child
2        203

I want to implement this in Informatica Cloud(IICS) Data Integration using loops. Any help or other approaches will be appreciated!

The solution would be to take the id e.g 203, match its corresponding D'id i.e. 110 to all other ids in the source. If found take the new id and check its corresponding D'id. If it is Null then we have found the parent if not we keep repeating this operation.
The solution to this is Looping and I'm not sure how to implement it in IICS. I have tried taskflows but didn't help much.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. Not in a generic way. You might achieve it if the number of hierarchy levels is known up front and limited, but a while-do / repeat-until solution won't be possible.
Unless you will use Java Transformation :)